# Importing function and getting props with "this": "TypeError: Cannot read property 'renderElapsedString' of undefined"

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I'm new to React and I'm creating a time logging app from the FullStackReact book, but using the ES6 'extends' module instead of Create Class. With that said, I'm getting this error and I'm out of ideas as to what's going on.

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'renderElapsedString' of undefined

**EDIT:** After removing the curly bracers from my 'helpers' import, I'm receiving a new error

> TypeError: __WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_2__helpers___default.a.renderElapsedString is not a function

**Final Edit:** The problem was my helpers.js file, I wasn't exporting the functions, which is why the function itself was undefined.

```
    import React from 'react';
    import EditableTimerList from './EditableTimerList';
    import helpers from '../helpers';

    class Timer extends React.Component {
      render() {
          const elapsedString = helpers.renderElapsedString(this.props.elapsed)
        return(
          <div className="ui centered card">
            <div className="content">
              <div className="header">
                {this.props.title}
              </div>
              <div className="meta">{this.props.projects}
              </div>
              <div className="center aligned description">
                <h2>{elapsedString}</h2>
              </div>
              <div className="extra content">
                <span className="right floated edit icon">
                  <i className="edit icon"></i>
                </span>
                <span className="right floated trash icon">
                  <i className="trash icon"></i>
                </span>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div className="ui bottom attached blue basic button">Start</div>
          </div>
        )
      }
    }

    export default Timer;
```

and here's my EditableTimer code

```
import React from 'react';
import helpers from '../helpers'
import EditableTimer from './EditableTimer'

class EditableTimerList extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div id="timers">
        <EditableTimer
          title="Learn React"
          project="Web Domination"
          elapsed='8986300'
          runningSince={null}
          editFormOpen={false}
        />
        <EditableTimer
          title="Learn Extreme Ironing"
          project="Web Domination"
          elapsed='3890985'
          runningSince={null}
          editFormOpen={true}
        />
      </div>
    )
  }
}

export default EditableTimerList;
```

And here's my helpers file:

```
    export function newTimer(attrs = {}) {
    return {
        title: attrs.title || 'Timer',
        project: attrs.project || 'Project',
        id: uuid.v4(), // eslint-disable-line no-undef
        elapsed: 0
    };
}

export function findById(array, id, cb) {
    cb(array.find(el => el.id === id));
}

export function renderElapsedString(elapsed, runningSince) {
    let totalElapsed = elapsed;
    if (runningSince) {
        totalElapsed += Date.now() - runningSince;
    }
    return millisecondsToHuman(totalElapsed);
}

export function millisecondsToHuman(ms) {
    const seconds = Math.floor((ms / 1000) % 60);
    const minutes = Math.floor((ms / 1000 / 60) % 60);
    const hours = Math.floor(ms / 1000 / 60 / 60);

    return [
        pad(hours.toString(), 2),
        pad(minutes.toString(), 2),
        pad(seconds.toString(), 2)
    ].join(':');

}

export function pad(numberString, size) {
    let padded = numberString;
    while (padded.length < size) padded = '0' + padded;
    return padded;
}

export default {
    millisecondsToHuman: millisecondsToHuman,
    newTimer: newTimer,
    findById: findById,
    renderElapsedString: renderElapsedString
};
```

Comment: console log the `helpers` and see what you are getting

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your classes look fine. The error indicates that the `helpers` object is undefined.

This is most likely because of the `export` in the helpers file.
Depending on how your are exporting helpers you will import them in a different way. In your `Timer` file:

```
import { helpers } from '../helpers';
```

should probably be

```
import helpers from '../helpers';
```

if helpers is being exported as a default. See [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import) for more info on import/export destructuring in es6.

Comment: I've removed the braces and now I'm receiving the following error:

"TypeError: __WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_2__helpers___default.a.renderElapsedString is not a function"

I've attached my helpers file for additional information

Comment: Turns out I wasn't even exporting the functions in my helper file! I neglected that file for some reason and was using the default one I was provided, which had no exports as it wasn't required in the tutorial code.