# Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'NON_INDEXED_FIELDS' of undefined

Tags: javascript, electron

I'm using electron and this [electron-builder](https://github.com/nklayman/vue-cli-plugin-electron-builder) to package my app. In one of my renderer processes I am importing dexie, and [dexie-encrypted](https://github.com/mark43/dexie-encrypted) like so:

```
import Dexie from "dexie";
import encrypt from "dexie-encrypted";
```

And in my the file I have this section of code:

```
encrypt(db, idbKey, {
  certStore: encrypt.NON_INDEXED_FIELDS,
});
```

So after building and opening the app I get the error:

Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'NON_INDEXED_FIELDS' of undefined

I've tried the solution from this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45047255/importing-function-and-getting-props-with-this-typeerror-cannot-read-proper) but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

Easy fix, just use

```
const encrypt = require("dexie-encrypted");
```

Then use:

```
encrypt.encryptDatabase(db, idbKey, {
  certStore: encrypt.NON_INDEXED_FIELDS,
});
```

That seems to do the trick!