# Access the TestCafe `t.testRun` data, using a global import of the test object

Tags: javascript, testing, automated-tests, e2e-testing, testcafe

I'm trying to add some trace headers to requests we send (as part of our automated tests), to help with debugging. My hope was to use `t.testRun.test.id`, so that we can link all requests back to the test... however I keep getting `TypeError: Cannot read property 'test' of undefined`.

I'm using the global import of `t`. Other than passing the test object (`t`) to every function, is there a way I can access the testRun object?

To reproduce, just do

```js
import { t } from 'testcafe';

fixture('<name>')
  .page('<page>')
  .beforeEach(async () => {
    console.log(await t.testRun.test.id);
  };

test('<name>', async () => {/*...*/});
```

Comment: hi, interesting, perhaps this might be of interest https://stackoverflow.com/a/45048894/11746212

Comment: Thanks for the link. Sadly not the case here; testcafe doesn't expose the testRun data in the way I had hoped.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get access to the test run info only from the `t` object obtained from the `test` or `beforeEach/afterEach` hooks:

```
  .beforeEach(async t => {
    console.log(await t.testRun.test.id);
  });
```

The globally imported `t` object contains only available actions like click, typeText, etc.

Note that you use a non-public undocumented API at your own risk.

Comment: That makes sense, but also a shame since I don't want to have to pass the `t` object through every function, just to log out the `id` further downstream.

Comment: At present, there is no other way to get a test id or name. Please track the following thread on GitHub to be notified of our progress with this feature: https://github.com/DevExpress/testcafe/issues/2826. Also, you can describe your requirements there.